# How to properly use gerunds, past participles, predicate nominatives, and appositive phrases in a single sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to construct a sentence that has a past participle modifying a predicate nominative, a gerund as the subject, and an appositive phrase renaming an object of the preposition.

I’ve been trying to come up with something for hours and have not gotten everything to work together.

Here is my current best attempt:

> Acting is difficult to which they foolishly chose John, a terrible actor.

Gerund subject: Acting
Past participle: chose John
Predicate nominative: John
And John renames the object of the preposition a terrible actor.

I know this is not right, but it’s really hard.

Comment: ELU is not actually a puzzle group...

Comment: Is there a better place to post this sort of question?

Comment: There is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ although you should check their rules before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start this off slow so you can get it right. I don't think you have assigned the right types of things to your terms.

For example, you can't just say *acting* is a gerund; it is not. It's simply an *-ing* inflection. Gerunds are *-ing* verb phrases used as a noun phrase for things like subjects, objects, or appositives.

And when you say "Acting is difficult", now your *Acting* is simply a noun and so clearly not a verb and hence not a gerund. Plus you have an adjective not a noun phrase after the verb, so that's not a predicate nominative either. It's just a predicate adjective instead.

So try a subject like "Lazily throwing my dog a ball", which now has your gerund heading the gerund clause. But remember it only becomes a gerund when used as a noun phrase, not before.

Then for a predicate nominative you need to use a copular verb, or at least an intransitive one, that connects to a noun phrase on the other side. I'll use the verb *be* in its past tense singular for my verb, and one of "good exercise for him" or "a piece of cake" or "my way of keeping myself out of trouble" for my noun phrase. That gives you three easy possibilities:

1. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was **good exercise for him**.
2. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was **a piece of cake**.
3. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was **my way of keeping myself out of trouble**.

Notice how Case 3 has gerunds as ***both*** the subject and the object of the preposition, here a predicate nominative rather than a predicate adjective etc.

Those all end with an object of a preposition. So all you need to do is give them a noun phrase used as an appositive. I'll choose noun phrases "my best friend in all the world" and "the anti-pie desert" and "my perennial nemesis" to use as appositives to the object of the preposition here, and in that order:

4. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was good exercise for him, **my best friend in all the world.**
5. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was a piece of cake, **the anti-pie dessert.**
6. Lazily throwing my dog a ball was my way of keeping myself out of trouble, **my perennial nemesis.**

Comment: Though this question is closed for reasons that escape me, I did want to thank you for this thorough answer to my question.  It is much appreciated.